# How do I make an infinite paged scroll view with image views?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a paged UIScrollView that automatically scrolls to the left through 4 UIImage views placed in sequence every 5 seconds. When the scroll view reaches the 4th image view it scrolls all the way back to the first image view and starts over again.

What would be the best approach to creating the illusion of an infinite scrollview? In other words instead of the scroll view going back at all, I just want it to keep scrolling forward and when it reaches the 4th image view, it scrolls forward and image view #1 is there.

I've thought of just re-adding the image views and increasing the content size of the scroll view when the scroll view reaches the 4th image but that wouldn't be very smart... idk

Here is my code so far:

My declarations:

```
var pageImages = [UIImage]()
var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
var scrollTimer = NSTimer()
@IBOutlet weak var carousel: UIScrollView!
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
pageImages = [UIImage(named: "featured_1.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "featured_2.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "featured_3.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "featured_4.png")!]
    for _ in 0..<pageImages.count
       pageViews.append(nil)
}
var pagesScrollViewSize = carousel.frame.size

        carousel.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count),
            height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

loadVisiblePages()
```

And the function called by the timer every 5 seconds:

```
func scrollToImage() {
        let x = carousel.contentOffset.x
        if (x <= (carousel.frame.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count))/2) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.carousel.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x+self.carousel.frame.width, 0)
        })
        } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.carousel.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.pageViews[0]!.frame.origin.x, 0)
        })
        }
    }
```

And finally the helper functions that do the bulk work:

```
func loadPage(page: Int) {
        if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
            return
        }

        if let pageView = pageViews[page] {

        } else {
            var frame = carousel.bounds
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
            frame.origin.y = 0.0

            let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
            newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
            newPageView.frame = frame
            carousel.addSubview(newPageView)
            pageViews[page] = newPageView
        }
    }

    func loadVisiblePages() {
        let pageWidth = carousel.frame.size.width
        let page = Int(floor((carousel.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

        let firstPage = page
        let lastPage = page + 3

        for index in firstPage...lastPage {
            loadPage(index)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea would be:

When an image goes out of frame on the left side, have it be removed and re-attached on the right side of the right-most image. At that point you reset the content offset

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageViews: [UIImageView] = []
    var scrollTimer = NSTimer()

    @IBOutlet weak var carousel: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        pageViews = [
            UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "featured_1.png")!),
            UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "featured_2.png")!),
            UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "featured_3.png")!),
            UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "featured_4.png")!)
        ]
        var pagesScrollViewSize = carousel.frame.size
        carousel.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageViews.count),height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)
        println(carousel.contentSize)

        scrollTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "moveLeft", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        showPage()
    }

    func showPage(){
        carousel.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
        for (index, page) in enumerate(pageViews) {
            var frame = page.frame
            frame.origin.x = carousel.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.origin.y = 0.0
            println(frame)
            page.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
            page.frame = frame
            carousel.addSubview(page)
        }

    }

    func moveLeft(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            1.0,
            animations: {
                let x = self.carousel.contentOffset.x
                self.carousel.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x + self.carousel.frame.width, 0)
                println(self.carousel.contentOffset)
            }, completion: {complete in
                self.moveLeftEnd()
            }
        );
    }

    func moveLeftEnd(){
        let first = pageViews.removeAtIndex(0)
        pageViews.append(first)
        showPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: This and I suggest you watch this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=104) which demonstrates how to achieve the effect.

Comment: This doesn't really work but thanks for the help and your time! The first image view scrolls to the next image then scroll view kind of flickers and we're back to the first image view. It's kind of an erratic loop between the first and second image views

Comment: I apologize, there was an error in one of the functions and i didn't see it because all my images looked the same. This works 100% now, check the edit i made, it replaces the moveLeftEnd() function.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks! What you're essentially doing is removing the image that has left the screen and adding it to the end of the array, correct? Will this have a significant impact on CPU? Also one problem I've noticed is that scrolling the image by hand leads to the image view being offset and the rest of the animation to mess up. This didn't happen with my old implementation. Is there any way of fixing this? Also I guess one caveat is being unable to scroll backwards, hmm

Comment: Finally figured out a much simpler method than the one above. Will answer the question in a bit